# Can apng or any other image filetype be animated over many years?

Tags: images, jpeg, png, animation

I am wondering if there is a suitable image type that can be animated or a layer can be animated to vanish over a long period of time... like years?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I made one here with the program [APNG Assembler](http://apngasm.sourceforge.net/) that should switch back and forth between red and green every ten years.

[image: Animated PNG]

[image: APNG Assembler]